# Macbook Pro 14.1 w/Ubuntu 20.04 LTS won't recognize flash drives

Tags: sound, usb, mount, usb-drive, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Macbook Pro 14.1 from a flash drive. Once installed, everything worked fine, except now it doesn't recognize there's a flash drive plugged in. I tried several drives including an SSD external drive. The drives work fine on my other laptop with Ubuntu, a Dell. I know at least one is formatted to FAT32, and all are compatible with Ubuntu on other computers.

How can I get the Macbook to recognize my flash drives are plugged in? Thanks in advance.

Edit: built-in keyboard and trackpad have worked since installation finished. Only USB ports broken.

Edit 2: Also not working: built-in speakers, headphones, bluetooth.

Comment: Does your built-in (NOT USB) keyboard and mouse work?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 as it's a *specialist* server product.  Ubuntu has releases that use the *year* format (20) but they are different to those using the *year.month* format (eg. 20 != 20.04).   You installed a server system as that's what 20 is.   *I don't understand the 2016; Ubuntu Core 20 is the 2020 release of the Ubuntu Core server product; 20.04 was the 2020-April release of Ubuntu Server/Desktop/.. product; Ubuntu Core 16 was from 2016*

Comment: The buiilt-in mouse trackpad did NOT work during installation, but keyboard did. As soon as installation was complete, the trackpad worked again without me doing anything.

Comment: I meant 20.04, sorry I was being a lazy typist and didn't realize there was a server version.

Comment: Please correct your question, the *year* format (20) has been used for *snap* only products of Ubuntu since 2016; Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server (or Desktop) are different products. You can correct your own question, but 20 is different to 20.04 and 20 is a *headless* product (ie. designed for use without screen as no desktop or GUI is provided; do note there is a server version of 20.04 too).  The 2016 is just unclear & needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get your MacBook with Ubuntu, I would recommend installing the drivers for your device. View [this](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7) guide for more information. To install hardware keyboard and mouse drivers:

1. Download files from https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver and https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver
2. Copy the .zip files to a directory (in separate folders) on your device
3. Go to a terminal and cd to the directory (`cd /path/to/directory`)
4. Run `make && make install` to install those drivers using the Makefile

This may also be able to fix the USB issue as well, hopefully.

Comment: My keyboard and trackpad worked fine after install, so I'm hesitant to install these drivers--if it ain't broke...

Do you think it's likely enough to affect USB ports to risk?

Comment: @Euskus I have no idea. I think that there could be an answer to your question on the guide. https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7 I would take a look at this and it could answer your question.